# Laravel: How to specify the number of items in pagination via route variable

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

I'm looking to change the number of items displayed via pagination, specified in the controller via the route below to set the amount of products to display on each page of pagination.

An example would be if the user entered `http://example.com/first-category?numProducts=99` they would be shown the view `'pages.category'` with 99 items in each page of the pagination. I assume I've got something wrong in the route, but need a little help please.

**Routes:**

```
//First returns single product
Route::get('/products/{cat}/{permalink}', 'ShopController@show')->name('shop.product');
//Second gets all items in category group
Route::get('/products/{cat}', 'ShopController@subIndex')->name('shop.cat');
//Third to pass variable prodNum to ShopController for paginate($prodNum)
Route::get('/products/{cat}?numProducts={prodNum}', 'ShopController@subIndexMore')
```

**ShopController.php**

The controller looks like this:

```
// Shows all items in category, set to 10 items per page via paginate(10)
public function subIndex($cat) {
  $category = Category::where('permalink', $cat)->first();
  $products = ProductGroup::where('category', $category->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(10);
  return view('pages.category',compact('products', 'category'));
}
// Shows all items in category, paginate($prodNum) determines how many items in each page
public function subIndexMore($cat, $prodNum) {
  $category = Category::where('permalink', $cat)->first();
  $products = ProductGroup::where('category', $category->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate($prodNum);
  return view('pages.category',compact('products', 'category'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify query string arguments in your route file. You can access them as inputs to your request.

```
public function subIndex(Request $request, $cat)
{
  $num_items = $request->input('numProducts');
  $category = Category::where('permalink', $cat)->first();
  $products = ProductGroup::where('category', $category->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate($num_items);
  return view('pages.category',compact('products', 'category'));
}
```

Remember to include:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: This is great, just what I needed, thanks. Never thought of just specifying the request

Comment: Just a quick note for anyone else who finds this in future I passed the request into the view and the code below in my blade to change pagination for any pages after the first:

`@if($request->get('numProducts'))
                                {{ $products->appends(['numProducts' => $request->get('numProducts')])->links() }}
                            @else
                                {{ $products->links() }}
                            @endif`

Answer (score 2):

For example `http://example.com/first-category?numProducts=99`, in this case `numProducts` is query string parameter use in the controller `$request`:

```
public function subIndex(Request $request, $cat) 
{
  $request->has('numProducts') ? $perPage = $request->get('numProducts') : 10;

  $category = Category::where('permalink', $cat)->first();
  $products = ProductGroup::where('category', $category->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate($perPage);
  return view('pages.category',compact('products', 'category'));
}
```

If you want to use `numProducts` as parameter in url, set route like this:

```
Route::get('/products/{cat}/{perPage}', 'ShopController@subIndexMore');
```

The controler:

```
public function subIndexMore($cat, $perPage) {
  $category = Category::where('permalink', $cat)->first();
  $products = ProductGroup::where('category', $category->id)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate($perPage);
  return view('pages.category',compact('products', 'category'));
}
```

and the URL will be:

```
http://example.com/first-category/99
```

Comment: @dhinchliff got in there first I'm afraid. I've taken your if statement however for the $perPage you've outlined and added that too. Thanks for the pointers!